# Does a cycle with a pause after each iteration inside MySQL stored procedure keeps locks during the pause?

Tags: mysql, sql, uitableview, stored-procedures, locking

Does a cycle with a pause after each iteration inside MySQL stored procedure keeps locks during the pause? I mean table or row locks, does not meter.

I am looking for an answer related to specified engine.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have  more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a lock, caused by a uncommitted transaction or manual lock, the lock keeps until commit transaction, unlock tables or close connection (and rollback). No matter if there is a delay after iterations if you reach the execution timeout the transactions and locking will be released..